# terminal not updating properly after changing .bashrc and .bash_profile

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm just trying to update my .bashrc and .bash_profile file on my new mac.
My files look like so:

// .bash_rc

```
orange=$(tput setaf 166);
yellow=$(tput setaf 228);
green=$(tput setaf 71);
white=$(tput setaf 15);
bold=$(tput bold);
reset=$(tput sgr0);

PS1="\[${bold}\]\n";
PS1+="\[${orange}\]\u";  # username
PS1+="\[${white}\] at ";
PS1+="\[${yellow}\]\h";  # host
PS1+="\[${white}\] in ";
PS1+="\[${green}\]\W :";   # working directory
PS1+="\n";
PS1+="\[${white}\]\$ \[${reset}\]"; # '$' and reset color
export PS1;
```

// .bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

My terminal looks like this:
[image]

I can't figure out what I've entered wrong. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Screenshot says you use `zsh` but you show Bash config files? And it's `.bashrc`, *not* `.bash_rc`.

Comment: Simply remove ```\[``` and ```\]``` to make fix the printing of those extra chars. But that will cause other problems.

Comment: `zsh` has an entirely different (and much improved) set of constructs for defining a prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using `zsh`, not `bash`; prompts are configured entirely differently.

Second, you need not export `PS1`, as any process that cares about its value will be sourcing `.zshrc`.

The following should work, placed in `.zshrc`:

```
# The variables aren't necessary, but retained for
# ease of updating. You could specify %F{15} directly
# for %F{$white}, e.g.
orange=166
yellow=228
green=71
white=15

PS1=$'%B\n'
PS1+="%F{$orange}%n"
PS1+="%F{$white} at "
PS1+="%F{$yellow}%m";
PS1+="%F{$white} in "
PS1+="%F{$green}%~ :"
PS1+=$'\n'
PS1+="%F{$white}%# %f%b"
```

`%B` and `%b` turn bold on and off, respectively. `%F{...}` changes the current foreground color; `%f` resets to the terminal default. The `\` escapes from `bash` are replaced with `%` escapes. You don't need the `zsh` equivalent of `\[...\]` anywhere, because you aren't using any raw byte sequences to control formatting.

The entire thing could be reduced to a single line:

```
PS1=$'%B\n%F{166}%n%F{15} at %F{228}%m%F{15} in %F{71}%~ :\n%F{15}%# %f%b'
```

though the longer version is more maintainable.

Finally, note that (unlike `bash`) `zsh` sources `.zshrc` for all interactive shells. If it's also a login shell, it sources `.zprofile`, before, not instead of, `.zshrc`.